# Qualifying for Careers 2.0

Tags: support, jobs

When they check if you qualify for Careers profile, do they only take in your history from StackOverflow, or from other computer related stack exchange websites as well?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  There are two options on the [request an invite page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/get-one).  If you're choosing to auto qualify with your StackOverflow account, we'll only be looking at your history from StackOverflow.  If you choose to request an invitation, we'll follow any link you provide including other computer related Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: So auto qualify is basically just an automated process that is only programmed to look to StackOverflow, where when request an invitation option is used there is actual humans reviewing the invitation?

Comment: Hwy Will Cole, How does career 2.0 inspect stackoverflow account? what are exact stackoverflow qualification like how much my reputation points should be to qualify?